# Lookup company metadata from weird string, after parsing SEC 13F files

Tags: r, web-scraping, finance

I want to download data from a SEC filing in R. The code below does this. It creates a data frame that contains the 13F data.

```
#einhorn_13F_2016.R
# Holdings of D. Einhorns Hedge Fund
# Metadata / Background Info
#https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1079114/000107911416000025/xslForm13F_X01/primary_doc.xml
library(ggplot2)
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# data
# read in HTML:
html_url <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1079114/000107911416000025/xslForm13F_X01/Greenlight_13FXML_06302016.xml"
html_dat <- read_html(html_url)

#find the right table in HTML DOM
html_dat <- html_table(html_dat, header = TRUE, fill=TRUE)[[4]]
glimpse(html_dat)

# parse messed-up table header
einhorn_col <- map2_chr(html_dat[1,],html_dat[2,], paste)
einhorn <- html_dat
colnames(einhorn) <-  make.names(stri_trim(stringi::stri_trans_tolower(paste0( einhorn_col, sep=""))))
einhorn <- einhorn[3:nrow(einhorn),]

# there are 2 important numeric columns
einhorn[, "value..x.1000."] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "",einhorn[, "value..x.1000."]))
einhorn[, "shrs.or.prn.amt"] <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", einhorn[, "shrs.or.prn.amt"]))

# most important holdings by value
einhorn %>%
        group_by(name.of.issuer) %>%
        summarise(sum_value=sum(value..x.1000.),sum_shares=sum(shrs.or.prn.amt)) %>%
        arrange(desc(sum_value))

# show some company names
companies <- unique(einhorn$name.of.issuer)
sample(companies, 6)
```

Now I want to augment the data frame.

```
colnames(einhorn)
 [1] "name.of.issuer"          "title.of.class"          "cusip"                  
 [4] "value..x.1000."          "shrs.or.prn.amt"         "sh..prn"                
 [7] "put..call"               "investment.discretion"   "other.manager"          
[10] "voting.authority.sole"   "voting.authority.shared" "voting.authority.none"
```

Starting from column 1, "name of issuer", I want to find the market category , country of residence etc.

I want output similar to the [finreportr::CompanyInfo("GOOG") call](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/finreportr/vignettes/finreportr.html)

```
  company        CIK  SIC state state.inc FY.end            street.address             city.state
  1 GOOGLE INC. 0001288776 7370    CA        DE   1231 1600 AMPHITHEATRE PARKWAY MOUNTAIN VIEW CA 94043
```

but when I enter values from the "name of issuer" column I don't know where to fetch this data from.

```
sample(companies, 6)
[1] "TAKE-TWO INTERACTIVE SOFTWAR" "TERRAFORM PWR INC"           
[3] "APPLE INC"                    "VOYA FINL INC"               
[5] "AERCAP HOLDINGS NV"           "PERRIGO CO PLC
```

Does not work with one of the values above (because it is not a real ticker value):

```
finreportr::CompanyInfo("TERRAFORM PWR INC")
```

Result:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> read_html.default
```

Is there a web service, API endpoint or R package that I can use to get this data?

Comment: Appears that you are asking for a tutorial in the use of the finreportr package. And you want us to unclude code that completes your work assignment of merging that material with what you have produced above. I have to agree with other closevoter that this is OT despite your having produced working code, because the request is is not really about how to do a specific task with the R objects you have.

Comment: Moderators: Instead of  closing this, move this to opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: @42: No, no, no. I want to find a package (not necessarily R) that accepts a company-name as input and produces a data set as output. I don't have the time to the check dozens of packages from the "Empirical Finance" task view. And there dozens of web-API data providers. It's just that I am not from the field of finance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I have used the [Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/) to look up company details from a strangely formatted and abbreviated string. It works in the majority of cases.

API Key handling/assignment omitted from code.

(...prepend code  from Question block here ....)

```
# show some company names
companies <- unique(einhorn$name.of.issuer)
#samp <- data.frame(company=sample(companies, 6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
samp <- sample(companies, 6)


kgapi_call_str <- function(query,
                           apikey,
                           templatestr="https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?key=%s&limit=1&indent=True&query=%s"){
        knowledgeapi <- sprintf(fmt = templatestr, apikey, URLencode(query))
        knowledgeapi
}


kg_api_call <- function(api_call_str, extracolumn=NA){
        json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(api_call_str)
        if(is.data.frame(json$itemListElement)) {
                json.result <- jsonlite::flatten(json$itemListElement)
                colnames(json.result) <- make.names(colnames(json.result) )
                json.result$name.of.issuer <- extracolumn
                json.result
        }

}


kgapi_call_data <- function(api_call_str, extracolumn=NA){
        extracolumn_shortened <- gsub('\\s+\\w+$', '', extracolumn, perl=TRUE)
        extracolumn_shortened.2 <- gsub('\\s+\\w+$', '', extracolumn_shortened, perl=TRUE)
        json <- kg_api_call(api_call_str, extracolumn)
        if(!is.null(json)){
                return(json)
        }
        # Query unsuccessful try shortened company-name,
        if (stri_length(extracolumn_shortened) > 0){
                message(sprintf("cannot resolve - 2nd try:\n%s\n%s\n\n", extracolumn, extracolumn_shortened))
                api_call_str <- kgapi_call_str(query=extracolumn_shortened, apikey=apikey)
                json <- kg_api_call(api_call_str, extracolumn)

                if(!is.null(json)){
                        return(json)
                }
        }

        if(is.null(json) & stri_length(extracolumn_shortened.2) > 0) {
                message(sprintf("cannot resolve - 3rd try:\n%s\n%s\n\n", extracolumn, extracolumn_shortened.2))
                api_call_str <- kgapi_call_str(query=extracolumn_shortened.2, apikey=apikey)
                json <- kg_api_call(api_call_str, extracolumn)
        }
        else {
                warning(sprintf("cannot resolve: \n%s\n%s\n\n", extracolumn, extracolumn_shortened))
        }

}

kgapi_lookup <- function(lookup_str, apikey) {
        dat <- kgapi_call_data(api_call_str=kgapi_call_str(query=lookup_str, apikey=apikey), extracolumn = lookup_str)
        dat
}

#kgapi_call_str("GENERAL MTRS CO", apikey)

companies.metadata.3 <- do.call(bind_rows, lapply(companies, kgapi_lookup, apikey))
companies.metadata.4 <- companies.metadata.3 %>%
        mutate(result..type=map(map(result..type, unlist), sort, decreasing=TRUE))

einhorn <- einhorn %>%
        left_join(companies.metadata.4, by="name.of.issuer")
```

Next time I try to use the CUSIP identifiers, which were also provided in the SEC 13F Form, but this service is non-free AFAIK.